# How can I logon and POST to RESTful resource protected by Spring Security?

Tags: spring, security, jpa, curl, spring-security

I am creating a RESTful web appliaction and am using Spring for the backend. When I wasn't implementing Spring Security, I could successfully add a new record to the JPA entity "Timestamp" by using a curl command from the command line. I am using Spring Security now so that when a user is not authenticated they are redirected to the login page. However now when I try curl to add a record with the following:

```
curl -i -X POST -v -u myusername:mypass -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "timestamp" : "2016-06-16T08:17:20.000Z", "peopleIn" : "1", "peopleOut":"0", "venue": "localhost://8181/venues/12" }' http://localhost:8181/timestamps
```

This is displayed in the terminal:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8181 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'harry.quigley2@mail.dcu.ie'
> POST /timestamps HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8181
> Authorization: Basic aGFycnkucXVpZ2xleTJAbWFpbC5kY3UuaWU6b2s=
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 118
>
* upload completely sent off: 118 out of 118 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A8EDFA6339DA76B11E0CDF6BB566A748; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A8EDFA6339DA76B11E0CDF6BB566A748; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://localhost:8181/login
Location: http://localhost:8181/login
< Content-Length: 0
Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sat, 28 May 2016 16:35:53 GMT
Date: Sat, 28 May 2016 16:35:53 GMT
```

I am getting a 302 redirect. Also every line is repeated twice - I'm not sure why this is.

My Spring Security Config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = CustomUserDetailsService.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/venue/new", "/static/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
                http.formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

If someone could understand why I'm being redirected and advise on what to change in order to be able to POST to the JPA entity, that would be great! Thanks

Comment: That URL does require authentication, did you set up basic auth?

Comment: "I am using Spring Security now so that when a user is not authenticated they are redirected to the login page."  That 302 *is* the redirect when you're doing cURL (which will also now need authentication), I think your question is how can you authenticate using cURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To authenticate with cURL you need to setup HTTP Basic authentication:

```java
http.httpBasic();
```